# PHP variable to HTML textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, getelementbyid

I am trying to place the PHP variable `$e` into HTML textbox `id="textid"` upon a button onclick. I have played around with various syntax, but I cannot seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ElementContent(id,content)
{
    document.getElementById(id).value = content;
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="" value ="" id="textid" ;"/>

<?php
$e = "test";
echo '<button value="" class="button" onclick="ElementContent(\'textid\',\'$e\')" />';
?>
```

Comment: A button is not self-closing. It should be `<button>label</button>`.

Comment: Not quite true, every tag can be self closed in XHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<button value="" class="button" onclick="ElementContent(\'textid\',\''.$e.'\')" />Button Name</button>';
```

You have to concat the string, as php doesn't automatically recognise dollars+some name as a variable in single quote strings.

Comment: fix this part `$e\.''`

Comment: `<button>` is not self-closing.

Comment: Also, notice `<input type="text" name="" value ="" id="textid" ;"/>` (superfluous `;"`). Might cause issues in certain browsers.

Answer (score 3):

PHP variables will only be interpreted in strings constructed with double-quotes (`"`). Update your code as follows:

```
<button value="" class="button" onclick="ElementContent('textid', '<?php echo $e ?>')" />
```

As you can see, there's no need to output the whole button markup in PHP. Thus, your final code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ElementContent(id,content) { document.getElementById(id).value = content; }
</script>

<input type="text" name="" value ="" id="textid" />

<?php $e = "test"; ?>
<button value="" class="button" onclick="ElementContent('textid', '<?php echo $e ?>')">Button</button>
```

I also took the time to fix a few issues with your markup, too.